# absolute layout on horizontal layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to het the same view for portrait and for horizontal. I need the box view to be in the middle of the grey stack layout its ok on portrait but once I switch to horizontal layout the aquamarine box view Is at the end of the stacklayout.  How do I get it in the middle for both layouts?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AbsolutePath"
                 x:Class="AbsolutePath.MainPage">
      <AbsoluteLayout>
            <AbsoluteLayout.Padding>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                    <On Platform="iOS">0, 20, 0, 20</On>
                </OnPlatform>
            </AbsoluteLayout.Padding>
            <!--<BoxView Color="LightGray"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, .35"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>-->
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1, .10, 1, .50" BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <Label Text="$11.95"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       FontSize="11"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" VerticalOptions="Center"
                         WidthRequest="350"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 1, 1, .65"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                         Padding="0, 10, 0, 0">
                <Label Text="Transaction History"
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <ListView>
                    <ListView.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>Transaction Item              +$15.00               9/9/19</x:String>
                            <x:String>Transaction Item              +$15.00               9/9/19</x:String>
                            <x:String>Transaction Item              +$15.00               9/9/19</x:String>
                            <x:String>Transaction Item              +$15.00               9/9/19</x:String>
                            <x:String>Transaction Item              +$15.00               9/9/19</x:String>
                            <x:String>Transaction Item              +$15.00               9/9/19</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </ListView.ItemsSource>
                </ListView>
           </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Using absolute values for positioning and sizing children can be problematic, because different devices have different screen sizes and resolutions. Therefore, the coordinates for the center of the screen on one device may be offset on other devices.You could try to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: I have read that Relative is not very good?

Comment: Maybe you could redefine the layout constraints when switching landscape.

Comment: It seems I can't access the Constraint of box view in back of the code    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
    Type=RelativeToParent,
    Property=Height,
    Factor=0.5}"

Comment: You could look at [Constraint objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout#constraint-objects) about how to do in behind codes.